# How do I set a property on a Storyboard UIViewController between segues on iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am trying to set a simple image on an UIImageView as such when a button is touched on the first view:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    ImageViewController *imageViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    imageViewController.title = @"test";
    imageViewController.imvBig.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
    imageViewController.lblTest.text = @"test2";
}
```

The .title gets set and appears just fine, but for some reason I can't get the imvBig.image to show up, nor can I get the label text to appear. Yes, I have the property created with an Outlet, etc (as I just dragged it over from IB right into the code and it was autocreated).

Can someone tell me how to properly set a property from one regular view to the next in a Storyboard setup?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the `ImageViewController` has not loaded its views from the storyboard yet when the system sends `prepareForSegue:sender:`, so those outlets (`imvBig` and `lblTest`) are nil.  Messages sent to nil are silently ignored.

It's usually not appropriate for the source view controller to muck around with the destination view controller's views.  The destination view controller should set those view's settings, usually in either `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear:`, or `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: I need to set a URL from a previous view on the navigation stack. I need to know how to pass data to the ImageViewController properly.

Comment: Usually you declare properties on the destination view controller for data you want to pass to it in prepareForSegue.  Then, in that view controller's viewDidLoad (or later if appropriate), update its views to reflect the data.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I was able to get this to work by creating an NSString property and then setting the label to the string on viewDidLoad of the ImageViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.lbltest.text = _myString;
}
```

I guess I can't set the property directly, until after the view is loaded.

Comment: It's both a "can't" and a "shouldn't" - you wouldn't want the calling view controller directly manipulating subviews in the new controller, since you might change how you want to display things some time later. Much better to just pass the data and sort out the correct way to display it in viewDidLoad().

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the viewController just use the segue destinationViewController property. I always set a identifier in the storyboard first so I can use multiple segues:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Show ImageViewController"]) {

[segue.destinationViewController setTitle:@Test"];
[segue.destinationViewController setFoo:@"Bar"];
//More stuff to set
}
```

}

also create an image in the ImageViewController as a property and synthesize it,then set that to the image view in the viewDidAppear:

```
self. imvBig.image = myNewImge;//this in the viewDidLoad
```

And Set that image in the segue:

```
[segue.destinationViewController setMyImage:[UIImage imageNamed@"test.png"]];
```